# Find matching strings between dictionary and list and replace matches with string

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dictionary and list. My dictionary contains values that are lists.

```
d={'Ro06_244736': ['A/A/A/A', 'R37', 'C/C/C/C'], 'Ro06_244742': ['G/G/G/G', '35', 'A/A/A/A']}

l=['R37', '35']
```

I am trying to find matching values between my list and my dictionary list's values, and if they match replace my dictionary list's values with 'N/A'. Matches can be at any element. I am wanting the following output.

```
d2={'Ro06_244736': ['A/A/A/A', 'N/A', 'C/C/C/C'], 'Ro06_244742': ['G/G/G/G', 'N/A', 'A/A/A/A']}
```

I have tried the following, but it didn't work :

```
for a,b in d.items():
    #print(a,b)
    for n, i in enumerate(b):
        #print(n,i)
        for j in l:
            #print(j)
            if i == j:
                print(i,j)
                b[n] = "N/A"
print(b)
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's because you're not actually editing the original list, rather you're editing the copy produced by `d.items()`.

Try assigning copy back into the dictionary after you have edited it.

```
for a,b in d.items():
  ...
     b[n] = "N/A"
  ...
  d[a] = b
```

Comment: Upvote because this is the issue of OP's code. But maybe it isn't `d10.items()` and `d10[a] = b`, it should be `d.items()`and `d[a] = b`.

Comment: @KevinMayo Looks like OP edited the name of their dictionary after I posted, updated now.

Answer (score 2):

The following code replaces anywhere in the list

```
In [9]: d={'Ro06_244736': ['A/A/A/A', 'R37', 'C/C/C/C'], 'Ro06_244742': ['G/G/G/G', '35', 'A/A/A/A']}
   ...:
   ...: l=['R37', '35']
   ...:

In [10]: for k,v in d.items():
    ...:     for index in range(len(v)):
    ...:         if v[index] in l: d[k][index] = "N/A"
    ...:

In [11]: d
Out[11]:
{'Ro06_244736': ['A/A/A/A', 'N/A', 'C/C/C/C'],
 'Ro06_244742': ['G/G/G/G', 'N/A', 'A/A/A/A']}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to do an easy list comprehension,use a `set`(would be faster,the original list is also okay) to save the element in the list:
Assume:

```
d = {'Ro06_244736': ['A/A/A/A', 'R37', 'C/C/C/C'], 'Ro06_244742': ['G/G/G/G', '35', 'A/A/A/A']}
l = {'R37', '35'}
```

One line:

```
d2 = {key: [item if item not in l else 'N/A' for item in values] for key, values in d.items()}
```

Result:

```
{'Ro06_244736': ['A/A/A/A', 'N/A', 'C/C/C/C'], 'Ro06_244742': ['G/G/G/G', 'N/A', 'A/A/A/A']}
```

Comment: You are using 3 level of nesting loop. It gets the job done, but efficiency wise I would prefer to reduce nested loop

Comment: @bigbounty Remove an unnecessary nest loop.Now only two levels nest.

Answer (score 1):

```
d={'Ro06_244736': ['A/A/A/A', 'R37', 'C/C/C/C'], 'Ro06_244742': ['G/G/G/G', '35', 'A/A/A/A']}

l=['R37', '35']

   for x,y in d.items():
    for i in y:
        if(i in l):
           y[(y.index(i))]="N/A"
print(d)
```

Comment: This will only check for 2nd element in the list.

Comment: So please reframe  your questions, your question had only 2 element

Comment: OP didn't say it's always the 2nd element

Comment: so it can be anywhere in list?

Comment: Because OP didn't mention that we have to assume it's anywhere in list

Comment: can you please check now

Comment: It's better to upvote bigbounty answer or remove your answer

Comment: It is any where in the list, not just element 2. I updated my variable names. Sorry, for the confusion.